When does $\varphi f \in L^2[0,1]$ for all $f \in L^2[0,1]$
I am trying solve this question: suppose $\varphi \in L^2[0,1]$, when does $\varphi f \in L^2[0,1]$ for all $f \in L^2[0,1]$?
My initial guess is  that $\varphi \in L^\infty[0,1]$. If $\varphi\in L^\infty[0,1]$, then it can be easily proved that $\varphi f \in L^2[0,1]$ for all $f \in L^2[0,1]$. But if $\varphi f \in L^2[0,1]$ for all $f \in L^2[0,1]$, I cannot prove that $\varphi \in L^\infty[0,1]$.
So I am asking the condition of $\varphi$, if $\varphi f \in L^2[0,1]$ for all $f \in L^2[0,1]$.  Many thanks in advance!
